# How can I properly delete a derived object I received from another DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, delete-operator, virtual-destructor

In my scenario I have a DLL with a base class. This DLL can load plugins. Each plugin DLL exports a create function which returns a derived object. I would prefer if the objects from the plugin DLLs could delete themselves.

In the following, I have written down two ways. Please ignore missing public/private statements. The first way is of course simpler because I only need to call delete as usual, but I am not sure whether it works. The second way does an explicit `delete this` because `this` must have the derived type, right?

```
// main DLL

class Base1
{
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Base2
{
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual void destroy() = 0;
};

// plugin DLL without destroy
class Derived1 : public Base1
{
    Derived1()
    {
        m_p = new cSomeClass;
    }

    virtual ~Derived1()
    {
        delete m_p;
    }

    cSomeClass * m_p;
}

// function which is exported
Base1 * createDerived1()
{
    return new Derived1;
}

// plugin DLL with destroy
class Derived2 : public Base2
{
    Derived2()
    {
        m_p = new cSomeClass;
    }

    virtual ~Derived2()
    {
        delete m_p;
    }

    virtual void destroy()
    {
        delete this;
    }

    cSomeClass * m_p;
}

// function which is exported
Base2 * createDerived2()
{
    return new Derived2;
}


int main()
{
    Base1 * pBase1 = createDerived1();
    delete pBase1;
    pBase = nullptr;
    // is derived object properly deleted?

    Base2 * pBase2 = createDerived2();
    pBase2->destroy();
    pBase2 = nullptr;
    // is derived object properly deleted?

}
```

Which one does "the right thing", i.e. properly delete the derived object using a base class pointer?

1. `delete` knows the object type and will properly delete it because of the virtual destructor.
2. Write a pure virtual destroy method which is implemented in the derived classes.
3. Export a destroy() method next to the create method which takes a `Base` pointer and does a dynamic cast before `delete`. (I have not written an example for this case because I find it unattractive.)

The first way seems to be the simplest because it does not require work beside properly writing virtual destructors.

Comment: Does the dll and the exe use the same version of the C++ runtime library? Do they use the same compiler options? If yes, and yes; then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory management between DLLs is a real pain.

In general memory allocated in one DLL must not be released in another.

Providing an explicit destroy (`delete this`) function, that must be called when the object is no longer needed, is the typical solution.

So go for 2 (write a pure virtual destroy method which is implemented in the derived classes):

```
class IBase
{
public:
  virtual void destroy() = 0;

  // Other pure virtual methods.
};

class Derived : public IBase
{
public:
   Derived() { m_p = new cSomeClass; }

   virtual ~Derived() { delete m_p; }

   virtual void destroy() override { delete this; }

private:
   cSomeClass *m_p;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IBase * __cdecl createDerived()
{
  return new Derived;
}
```

For further details you can read the GREAT [Exporting C++ classes from a DLL](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll) (from Eli Bendersky's website).

Answer (score 0):

no need separate delete func in child classes. update to **manlio** post:

// define abstaract class and func in header

```
#ifdef _EXPORTING
#define CLASS_DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CLASS_DECLSPEC    __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
class CLASS_DECLSPEC IBase
{
public:
  // implement function in parent class
  void destroy(){delete this;};

  virtual ~IBase(){};

  // Other pure virtual methods.
};
```

// import header file in dll source

```
class Derived : public IBase
    {
    public:
       Derived() { m_p = new cSomeClass; }
       virtual ~Derived() { delete m_p; }
    private:
       cSomeClass *m_p;
};
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IBase * __cdecl createDerived()
{
  return new Derived;
}
```